# Distortion In Pose Mode

Tags: pose-mode, makehuman

Import figure from Makehuman.
Sculpt hat.
Pose mode and something goes wrong?
[image: Pic 01]

[image: Pic02]

[image: Pic 03]

Comment: I think I know the problem, I use CARVER to cut the top of hair off so the hat fits better. It does not seem to join up correctly.

Comment: Just a guess, but I think the hat has lost its weight painting. Select the hat, go into weight painting, and make sure all the verts are painted to the head